# Limit network bandwidth between two interfaces by redirecting it via a vritual interface

Tags: iptables

I have a 4G failover, `hp`, to which I need to limit bandwidth from the main network `br0` so that the data allowance doesn't get used up.

This seems to be impossible because you limit a whole interface.

Therefore I thought:

- create a virtual network interface `br0hp` say,
- route all traffic from `br0` to `hp` via `br0hp`
- `wonderrshaper br0hp 28 28`

Does that sound right?

So:

```
# ip link add br0hp type dummy
```

and then add to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto br0hp
iface br0ho inet static
        address 192.168.0.114 # Does it need an address?
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And now I think the rest is `iptables` and this is what I'm struggling with. In particular: how to do the redirecting from `br0` to `hp` via the new `br0hp`. I guess it should go something like this:

```
# Traffic from br0 to hp should go to br0hp instead.
iptables -A PREROUTING -i br0 -o hp --out-interface br0hp -j MASQUERADE  
# Or is it MASQUERADE or SNAT or DNAT?

# Traffic from br0 to hp is not allowed.
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o hp -j DROP

# Masquerade
iptables -A FORWARD -o hp -i br0hp -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

# Limit
wondershaper br0hp 28 28
```

Or is it `ip route` that I need?

Comment: Wondershaper uses a different command line syntax, no? `wondershaper -a br0hp -u 28 -d 28`

Comment: Is "br0" the primary WAN, and "hp" the 4G backup?